# How do I swap from default Hibernate to Hibernate OGM

Tags: hibernate, jpa, web-applications

I have a maven project that creates a .WAR web service (and a .JAR with the same war but with tomcat embedded) and it originally uses Hibernate. I'm now trying to "transform" this project Hibernate to Hibernate OGM with MongoDB because I need to get performance time comparisons between both. but I don't really know how to do the transformation.

With this changes, it compiles without issues but I don't know if it uses the OGM framework instead of the original (which is relational). I'm lost right now, if someone tell me how to see if I'm using OGM and if not, what changes do I need in my program at first glance.

I've seen tutorials these last 2 days and I include all dependencies needed in pom.xml file for hibernate ogm and I've tried to create a persistence.xml in src/META-INF/persistence.xml and src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml in order to use this configuration (even though I can't find this file in the original project).

this is my pom.xml dependencies

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JAVA RX -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JERSEY -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>2.27</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
            <version>2.27</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-declarative-linking</artifactId>
            <version>2.27</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JACKSON -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>2.27</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- LOG4J -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- SWAGGER -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-jersey2-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- HIBERNATE -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Hibernate OGM Infinispan module; pulls in the OGM core module -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.ogm</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-ogm-infinispan-embedded</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Optional, needed to run JPQL queries on some datastores -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-search-orm</artifactId>
            <version>5.11.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Standard APIs dependencies - provided in a Java EE container -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.ogm</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-ogm-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Add the Narayana Transactions Manager an implementation would be provided in a Java EE container, but this works nicely in Java SE as well -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.narayana.jta</groupId>
            <artifactId>narayana-jta</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-transaction-spi</artifactId>
            <version>7.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.16.1-GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- C3P0 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- DERBY -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
            <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
            <version>10.13.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
            <artifactId>derbyclient</artifactId>
            <version>10.13.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- MYSQL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.14</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- POSTGRES -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- UIMA -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.uima</groupId>
            <artifactId>uimafit-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- DKPRO -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.clearnlp-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- DKPRO Models -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.clearnlp-model-dictionary-en-default</artifactId>
            <version>20130715.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.clearnlp-model-tagger-en-ontonotes</artifactId>
            <version>20131128.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

With this changes, it compiles without issues but I don't know if it uses the OGM framework instead of the original (which is relational). I'm lost right now, if someone tell me how to see if I'm using OGM and if not, what changes do I need in my program at first glance.

Comment: How do you create the Session/EntityManager factory? At start up in the log it should tell you if it's using MongoDB but you can also  check if something has been stored in the db or if there is a connection error when MongoDB is down. Could you also show the persistence.xml?

Comment: I don't have any Session/EM factories. When I run it uses the embeded derby database of Tomcat by default. Furthermore, there is no persistence.xml to be found in this version of the project (the one i have to modify) as it seems. I told that creating by myself a persistence.xml and putting the right stuff as the tutorial of HibernateOGM tells in this file seems like this file is being ignored and it still uses the same relational database as before.

Comment: If you are using Hibernate ORM to connect to Derby, at some point you should have, somewhere, a call to a session (or an entityManager). Otherwise how are you using Hibernate? I'm asking because this is what the persistence.xml is supposed to define.  Where is it defined in the code that derby should be used as db? Somewhere you should have set the property hibernate.connection.driver_class to org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver